# C# Click HTML Button without ID on webbrowser

Tags: c#, html

Im trying to code on c# so a button is clicked on the webbrowser.

The button has no ID

here is the html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit">Log me in</button></form>
```

how can i click this button without a id?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the WatiN Library to perform various kinds of web page operation.

First download WatiN and add a reference to it. The code is very simple to implement, you may see the docs [here](http://watin.org/)

WatiN is used like this:

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
  }
}
```

And in your case, you may use the Class attribute to get the button. There are plenty of samples.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, that can be done by clicking the button based on the class instead of the id, so for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        alert("Bingo")
    })   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the elements by the tag name and then find the exact one you are looking for by looking at the inner text:

```
var buttons = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

foreach (HtmlElement button in buttons)
{
    if (button.InnerText == "Log me in")
    {
        button.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: No disrespect john but don't you think this is an unnecessarily complicated approach? I think the JQuery provides a much easier solution.

Comment: @PierreOverFlow It all depends on how the original poster was performing his work.  If he is loading a page into a webbrowser control then this is a good approach.  If he controls the page and wants to perform the work client side, then I agree that the jQuery approach is the correct approach.  The reason I answered using this approach was because the question contained the term webbrowser as a single term leading me to believe he was using the control.