# C# Target HTML button by class

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I want to click on a button which doenst have an ID. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986652/c-sharp-click-html-button-without-id-on-webbrowser) stackoverflow question to get started, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
        //Load page 
        WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("/login");
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

        //Log in

        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("Value", "--");
        doc.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("Value", "--");
        doc.GetElementById("_submit").InvokeMember("Click");


        WebBrowser webBrowser2 = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser2.Navigate("/Start");
        while (webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
           System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();


        var buttons = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
       Console.WriteLine(buttons); **//Output here: 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection'**
        foreach (HtmlElement button in buttons)
        {
            
            if (button.InnerText == "Filter    ")
            {
                
                button.InvokeMember("Click");
                Console.WriteLine("Clicked!"); **// This will never get writing into the console.**
            }
        }


}
```

The HTML:

```
    <button class="down-arrow-btn" type="button" id="toggleFilterFieldsButton"
        title="Overige filtervelden tonen/verbergen"> ▼
</button>
<button class="filter-btn" type="submit" name="filter_action" title="Filteren"
        style="color: #7989a0"
        value="filter">Filter
</button>
<button class="herstel-btn" type="submit" name="filter_action" title="Filteren opheffen, alles tonen"
        value="reset">Herstel
</button>
```

In this case I want to press the second button.

**Edit:**

**First solution:**

```
             var element = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        .Cast<HtmlElement>()
        Where(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.GetAttribute("name")) && e.GetAttribute("name") == "filter_action")
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Second solution:**

```
         var elementToClick = webBrowser2.Document
        .GetElementsByTagName("button")
        .Cast<HtmlElement>()
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("className") == "filter-btn");
        elementToClick.InvokeMember("Click");
        Console.WriteLine(elementToClick);
```

I have tried multiple other solutions. But the htmlElement is always null.
I think the problem is due to the website being pretty secured. And the button I am targeting is not visible for the program? Even tho it's visible in the code.
If I copy the whole HTML code (view-source:https:// url ) and make it an local .html, it works fine. (all of the 3 solutions.)

Comment: Is it possible your comparison 'if (button.InnerText == "Filter    ")' isn't correct? Have you tried outputting the button.InnerText to the console to verify that you are both getting multiple buttons from your GetElementsByTagName("button") as well as to verify that the InnerText you are comparing against is accurate?

Comment: Thats a great idea. I tested it, but it seems like the program doenst even reaches the foreach.... 
Because the output is nothing. And if i try to Console.WriteLine("Test"); It also doesnt output anything.

Comment: Okay, So what I did: I created an .HTML file on my pc (local)

Only pasted the HTML buttons in and now I do see all the 3 button names. 
So I reckon after loging in, something goes wrong..

Is there a way, I can see what the program does visually? Like I am watching it execute?

Comment: Where does the URL for WebBrowser2 come from? Does it have any relation to your login in the first WebBrowser control?

Comment: Yess, definitely! 
First page = /login
Second page = /home --> I am not sure but i dont have to nagivate to this one right? because when you login, it will automatically redirect to here. Or is that what i am doing wrong?
Third page = /start --> and here are the buttons.

Comment: Right, you shouldn't need the second web browser control, only the first since after you login it should automatically be at the page you need. Try getting rid of it and making the webBrowser2 references webBrowser1

Comment: I changed that, while also adding form buttons, meaning the code has been split up.
It works! I think having muliple web browser controls isn't smart, and also the page didnt react quick enough to the code. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Glad you got it working. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Using only 1 web browser control did the trick.